# How to loop through jdbc request in while loop until the column has certain value in JMeter

Tags: jdbc, jmeter, performance-testing

I have to fire up a request to the oracle server. The request just creates a job which runs on background and updates a field (say STATUS) in database. From JMeter, After firing the request, the resultset contains some value like "your job is running". Now I have to loop through the JDBC request to capture the fiend STATUS until its value is "Ready". When it is so, then then the request should stop, and I need the time from firing of first request to the time it took to change the status to ready.
For this I added the following components

```
 - THREAD GROUP
 - JDBC CONNECTION CONFIGURATION
 - WHILE Controller (  condition = (${status.get(0).get("STATUS")}!="READY")    )
    -- JDBC Request (Result variable name = status )
 - Tree View Listener
```

The problem is, the while loop keeps executing even if the value of resultset is "READY", which is visible in the Tree View Listener.
Please somebody tell me what should I do.?

Comment: The while loop keeps running even for the following query.

SELECT 'READY' STATUS from dual;

The version of JMeter is 2.9 r1437961

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following and it Worked.

```
THREAD GROUP
JDBC CONNECTION CONFIGURATION
.. WHILE Controller ( ${__javaScript("${status_1}" != "READY")} )
  .. JDBC Request ( Variable name = status )
Listeners
```